# Why do I exactly need package.xml?

Tags: ros, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cause I need to duplicate all my build dependencies when I call find_package, then I need to set them into catkin_package,
then i need to set add_dependencies. How does package.xml help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220531/why-do-i-exactly-need-package.xml?/) by [msporyshev](https://answers.ros.org/users/25017/msporyshev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer (from @Dirk Thomas):

> [..] the CMake file is not "machine readable". It can contain arbitrary logic in CMake and can't be read without interpreting the CMake code. The XML on the other hand can easily be read.

Longer answer: see [CMakeLists.txt vs package.xml](http://answers.ros.org/question/217475/cmakeliststxt-vs-packagexml/).

---

Edit:

> [..] then i need to set add_dependencies [..]

Just a note: that is only required to make sure code generation for message and service definitions is run *before* any of the files that include those get compiled (you need to 'help' CMake a bit to understand the dependency hierarchy there). In general: no code generation to depend on, no need for `add_dependencies(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0